# How to load .bashrc from "bash -c"

Tags: bash

Trying to run a function defined in my .bashrc using "bash -c ". I end up with the error "command not found". How do I get "bash -c" to load my init file?

Answer (score 21):

You can make it into an interactive shell with `-i`, then your ~/.bashrc
will be read:

```
bash -i -c "echo \$EDITOR"
```

The other thing you can do is source the file explicit. If you have `/var/tmp/test` with content:

```
export XXX=123
```

and you do

```
bash -c "source /var/tmp/test; echo \$XXX"
```

you will get `123` echoed.

Comment: This doesn't work either: the `-i` fails with this same issue ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/27581210/293735 ), and I cannot use the `-l` since that'd reload the `.profile` (which I want to avoid) and the explicit source doesn't work (bash 4.3.30 on Ubuntu, maybe it's platform specific?)

Comment: @berdario the `-i` flag does work, it will run an interactive shell which reads `~/.bahshrc` and, since it is interactive, also enables aliases. How exactly did it fail for you? You're linking to an answer on SO that does not describe failure and the question is very specific and is about calling bash from within a perl script. Is that what you're doing? In any case, I couldn't repeat the OP's issue, it worked as expected even within Perl.

Comment: @terdon invoking `bash -i` stops the **outer** process, this happens with anything as the caller process (I personally tried with Python and Ruby)... but indeed something weird is happening: I could reproduce it on Ubuntu (I'll try again this evening at home), but I cannot reproduce it on Nixos and Kali

Comment: @berdario it sounds like your issue is quite specific. I suggest you ask a new question and link back to this one explaining how the answers here don't work for you.

Comment: Well, I think that this answer is wrong (and yours might be correct, but I want to double check on my machine before jumping to any conclusion).

Comment: I forgot what was the snippet that I was using to test it (the issue is exactly the same on other linux distributions as well)... I confirm that this fails in the general case (the general case where you're not only trying to execute shell functions/builtins): try `python3 -ic "import os; os.system(\"bash -ic ls\")"`

Answer (score 11):

Another option would be to set the `$BASH_ENV` variable:

```
   When bash is started non-interactively, to  run  a  shell  script,  for
   example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment, expands
   its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the  name
   of  a  file to read and execute.  Bash behaves as if the following com‐
   mand were executed:
          if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
   but the value of the PATH variable is not used to search for  the  file
   name.
```

So, you could do:

```
BASH_ENV=~/.bashrc && bash -c 'your_function'
```

Comment: `bash --rcfile ~/.bashrc -c 'echo $FOO'` **doesn't** print `bar` as expected

Comment: @berdario no, it doesn't. Thanks for pointing it out, I could have sworn I had tested it. The problem is that the `--rcfile` is only used when launching an interactive shell and `bash -c` launches a non-interactive one. Setting `BASH_ENV` does work though, did you try that?

Comment: This doesn't work either: with `export FOO=bar` in the `.bashrc`, `> echo $BASH_ENV\n
/home/dario/.bashrc\n
> bash -c 'echo $FOO'\n`: no output except the newline

Comment: @berdario I'm not sure exactly what you did but try this: `BASH_ENV=~/.bashrc bash -c 'echo $FOO'`. I just tested that on my system with `FOO=bar` in `~/.bashrc` and it worked as expected. If it doesn't, please ask a new question and link back to this one because your issue will be different.

Comment: Upon running `set -xe && source ~/.bashrc` I realized that apparently bash can silently swallow some errors when sourcing... these errors will make the sourcing silently fail. Since this got out of hand I opened a new question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187738/invoke-subshell-command-with-loaded-rcfile